# Strapi can't disable cors

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, strapi

Currently im facing an issue that can't dissable the cors from middleware.js file... My `./config/middleware.js` file is as follows. Any idea what is happening here?

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    cors: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "disable cors"? Do you want to not send CORS headers, or do you want to make the API open to anybody?

Answer (score -1):

```
     load: {
       before: ['timer', 'responseTime', 'logger', 'cors', 'responses', 'gzip'],
       order: [],
       after: ['parser', 'router'],
     },
     settings: {
       timer: {`enter code here`
         enabled: true,
       },
       cors: {
         enabled: true,
         origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://backend.com'],
       },
     },
   }
```

So the above code worked for me on my local env (Strapi and React). I will update how the production / staging env works like.

You would want to add the above piece of code in config/middleware.js
This may mean creating the file if it does not exist of which it doesn't most of the time.